# How to remove integers but keep the floats from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, types, floating-point, integer

I have a dictionary shaped like this:

```
{'Afghanistan': 0.0,
 'Albania': 0,
 'Algeria': 50.0,
 'Angola': 51.85185185185185
 'Vietnam': 48.333333333333336,
 'Yemen': 25.0,
 'Zambia': -105.55555555555556,
 'Zimbabwe': -570.0,
 'Global': -24.358974358974358}
```

As you can see some values are 0 where some are 0.0. I need to remove all dictionary entries where the value is 0, and keep the rest. How should i handle this? In this instance only Albania would have to be removed, but Afghanistan (which is also 0) should be kept.

I have tried a nested for-loop like this:

```
  for x in range(len(dictionary)):
    for y in dictionary:
        if issubclass(type(y[x]), int):
            dictionary.pop(y)
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: It seems that `isinstance(value, int)` is what you want.

Comment: Are you working with [moon knight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20323201/moon-knight)? This looks similar to his dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested loops, just one loop. The value of the dictionary element would be `dictionary[y]`.

And I'm not sure what you mean by `y[x]`. `y` is a dictionary key, `x` is an integer, so `y[x]` is one of the characters in the country name; this will get an error is `x` is more than the length of the country.

You shouldn't modify the dictionary while you're looping over it, so create a new dictionary.

```
new_dictionary = {key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if not isinstance(value, int)}
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/bo7HDt)

Comment: Thanks, i get the error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2), how would i go about in solving this?

Comment: Sorry, forgot `.items()`

Comment: What do you mean by that? .items() is in your code right?

Comment: I just added it in the last edit.

Comment: Thanks again, i now however get the error:
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Isn't `dictionary` the dictionary you showed in the question? It's not a float.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. I've added a link to an online demo.